# Provider hosted app and another server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, provider-hosted-app

I have a task: Do a Sharepoint Provider-hosted app. I work/develop locally, on a single machine.

From MSDN :

> Provider-hosted SharePoint Add-ins include components that are deployed and hosted outside the SharePoint farm. They are installed to the host web, but their remote components are hosted on another server that should not be a server in the SharePoint farm.

Requirement - another server - necessary?

I want to keep on the same server farm and remote components.
I do not want to put a second server.

Comment: For a development scenario you can surely host them on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually *need* a seperate server/VM. But it's recommended.

One realtively simply way would be an Azure account to host your app there (I think there are even free accounts possible). The advantage is, that you are cloud compatible and could migrate to SharePoint online very easily.